# How to fire an Event from OCX app (Activex FORM) to client - Delphi xe3?

Tags: vb.net, delphi, activex, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to Fire an event to a third party applicaction (the client).

I created a new Method in the Dispatch Interface, this method is called with a particular name (xxx), because the client it's going to take it and act...

I based my `ActiveX` method on a `VB.net` example (this example works great).

The example creates a `Public EVENT` and then call it on a `ONCLICK` button making a `RAISE EVENT xxx`

Based on the VB.NET example (given by the client) the app will act when my OCX app fire the xxx

event/method/procedure. I'm having problems to achieve this, because i dont have clear how to do it. –

Comment: The client won't do anything unless they subscribe to the event

Comment: Based on the VB.NET example (given by the client) the app will act when my OCX app fire the event/method/procedure "xxx".
I'm having problems to achieve this, because i dont have clear how to do it.